# How to send each received message when we receive many message at a time in android

Tags: android

I have made an xmpp chat application.I also made a twist that,when ever  I am getting a message from different users i am redirecting that message to a particular mobile number as sms. Now my problem is that when i am getting many messages at a time only 1 or 2 messages is getting delivered to that mobile number,rest of the message getting missed .Can anybody help me to solve this problem.My program code is shown below :

```
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                                .getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved " + message.getBody()
                                + " from " + fromName );
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        String st=message.getBody();
                        String res=sendSms(SERVER,st);
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please use this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/21426927/900338 than you are resolve your problem

Answer (score 1):

This way you can resolve your problem

```
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from " + fromName );
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }

private void setListAdapter() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listitem, messages);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```